# MSQL Consultas y Subconsultas (MQSL)

Tags: mysql

No se como poner la funcion MONTH() en una consulta o subconsulta, cuando lo pongo me da error.

```
SELECT MONTH('octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre')
  FROM Pedidos WHERE (
    SELECT SUM(Cantidad) AS ‘Total_Suma’, 
      AVG(Cantidad) AS ‘Total_Media’
      FROM pagos WHERE (
        SELECT Pais FROM Clientes WHERE (Pais=’USA’)
      )
  );
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). E incorpora el código de tus intentos. Preferimos enseñarte a pescar que darte peces, si vemos lo que has intentado, podremos ayudarte a mejorar. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: Ya esta modificado con pregunta

Comment: De verdad, envíanos las tablas pedidos y pagos, e indica el resultado que te gustaría obtener. Está genial que hayas intentado hacer la consulta, demuestra tu interés, pero tienes que darnos más información para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Buenas Vash. ´MONTH()´ devuelve el **mes** partiendo de una fecha. Por lo tanto tu problema viene de la sintaxis que estas usando. Te dejo esto para que le eches un ojo:  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_month.asp

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es obtener los datos de los meses de `octubre, noviembre y diciembre`? En ese caso, puedes escribir la consulta así: `SELECT MONTHNAME(LaColumnaTipoFecha) FROM ... WHERE MONTH(LaColumnaTipoFecha) >= 10` Si hay que filtrar por año, puedes usar la función `YEAR` aplicada a la columna de fecha. Si quieres los nombres de meses en castellano y se presentan en inglés puedes indicarlo también antes de ejecutar la consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

falta saber de qué tipo es la columna que estás consultando en la tabla 'pedidos' con MONTH(), y si es la que contiene la fecha. El valor de esa columna podría ser algo así '2019-10-10' o con una hora también añadida.

Partiendo de ahí, si usas MONTH() el parámetro que debes ponerle dentro es el nombre de esa columna en la que está la fecha.

Un ejemplo... quiero hacer una consulta de todas las compras realizadas en octubre, noviembre y diciembre:

```
SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE MONTH(fecha_de_compra) >= 10;
```

El resultado filtra los registros en los que coincida 'fecha_de_compra' con '10, 11 y 12' que son octubre, noviembre y diciembre.

Comment: Hola @Davidhachemartin, me consta que respondes por tratar de echarle una mano al OP porque yo lo he hecho en varias ocasiones aunque, créeme, hasta que no formulan bien la pregunta, de verdad que no funciona. Incluso posiblemente alguien de la comunidad os puntúe negativo a él y a ti por responderle. :) Bienvenido a [so], échale un vistazo a [ask] y espero verte por aquí en muchas más ocasiones.

Comment: Disculpa @David, tienes razón y no me había dado cuenta. No me lo tengas en cuenta que soy junior jeje. Gracias por el aviso y los enlaces. ¡Nos vemos por aquí! :)

Comment: Nada hombre, si a mí me pasó lo mismo y no hace tanto.. los veteranos parecen cascarrabias pero te ayudan un montón, al final han conseguido crear un ambiente muy bueno y no hay día que no aprendas algo nuevo